# Why does the following code hits IOException?

Tags: java

Client Class

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        {
            System.out.println(" Starting Client ");
            Socket socket = new Socket ("localhost",55555);
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
            printWriter.println("Hello from client");
            printWriter.println("Conected, Yes!");
            socket.close();// Changes as suggested by Jack
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }


    }
}
```

Server Class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(" inside main ");
        try 
        {
            System.out.println("Starting Server");
            ServerSocket serverSocket= new ServerSocket(55555);
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine= bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) 
            System.out.println("Server Message:"+inputLine);

        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("IOException "+e);
        }
    }
}

Output:
Starting Server
Server Message:Hello from client
Server Message:Conected, Yes!
IOException java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Client and Server java files are in the same package.
What would trigger IOException in the following code?
Is it something to do with Eclipse?
    FYI, I am using Eclipse SDK
    Version: 4.2.2
    Build id: M20130204-1200

Comment: Could you print the details of the exception and add it here? At the server side instead of printing `"IOException " + e` do `"IOException " + e.getMessage()`

Comment: What version of JDK are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jack mentioned in his answer you need to close() your socket before the client application exit.

Socket is AutoCloseable

The safe way of work with closable resource is creation in `try` block:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(" Starting Client ");
            try(Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 55555)) {
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                printWriter.println("Hello from client");
                printWriter.println("Conected, Yes!");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

and it will be closed automatically on exit (from try section).

Comment: Glad to help. You can accept my answer to close this topic.

Comment: I don't see an option to close this topic.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your client opens a `Socket`, sends some data and then exits the program, thus abruptly closing the connection.

You should call `close()` on the `Socket` from the client side to notify the server that the socket it is going to be closed.